# How to create a bottom menu in Android while keeping the top menu?

Tags: java, android

I want to be able to create a popup menu from the bottom when the user hits the menu button on their phone, but I want it separate from the top menu. On my top menu, I have a `DrawerLayout` and a search icon which I want to stay on top, but I want a menu to popup from the bottom when the user clicks the menu button. Is there an easy way to achieve this, because it seems like Android tries to bundle all the extra icons in the overflow menu.

Here's a picture of what I have, and I just want the menu button to pop up a menu from the bottom.
[image]

Comment: Simply create your own custom bottom layout as the default SplitActionBar cannot be controlled and behaves depeding upon the screen size and space available. :)

Comment: Do you have any documentation or examples that can help me out with that? I'm guessing I need to override the `onCreateOptionsMenu` function, but I'm not sure how I would do this with a custom layout and whatnot. Thanks.

Comment: For the upper action bar you go through https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html and a cool tool http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: For the lower actionbar you can create a linearlayout or anything else you prefer, thats a custom layout I am talking abou. Lemme know if you need more details.